# Jquery json requested okey, but no results

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code queries for some json but there seems not to be a result. When debugging using firebug, I can see that the request is done and returns the expected json  (bottom).

The problem is that the next line, (var option =...) is never reached, so I expect that I did some thing wrong?

```
$.getJSON("Gateway.php?action=UserAction&subAction=json", function(result) {
    var options = $("#creatorUserId");
    $.each(result, function(item) {
        options.append($("<option />").val(item.id).text(item.value));
    });
});
```

The json:

```
json[{"id":"1","value":"Teddy"},{"id":"2","value":"Fred"},{"id":"3","value":"Roel"}]
```

Comment: Does your response include those characters at the beginning `json`? That isn't valid json, and jquery will consider that failure and then not execute the success callback (but rather fail silently).

Comment: Moreover, what you see in firebug is most likely the synchronous execution of the call, but not the response. I.e. if you step through a debugger when running the getJSON you're not expected to execute the callback and see it running, since it doesn't do so synchronously.

Comment: Ah, there was an echo some where deep in the code that echoed "json". Didn't solve the problem though. On your second comment: It is the response, of the get Gateway.php... on the firebug console and not on the debugger itself.

Comment: Damn cache! It did solve it ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback for `$.each()` takes (up to) two parameters -- the first is an index number, and the second is a value. Your `item` is always an index number, not the item object.

Try this:

`Gateway.php?action=UserAction&subAction=json` should return:

```
[{"id":"1","value":"Teddy"},{"id":"2","value":"Fred"},{"id":"3","value":"Roel"}]
```

javscript/jquery:

```
$.getJSON( "Gateway.php?action=UserAction&subAction=json", function(result) {
        var options = $("#creatorUserId");
        $.each(result, function(num,item) {
            options.append($("<option />").val(item.id).text(item.value));
        });
    });
```

Or, to use slightly less jQuery:

```
$.getJSON( "Gateway.php?action=UserAction&subAction=json", function(result) {
        var options = $("#creatorUserId");
        while(result) {
            var item = result.shift();
            options.append($("<option />").val(item.id).text(item.value));
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't solve the initial problem but fixed the rest of the script.

Comment: I was using this technique in my own code today, and discovered that while `$.ajax` supports an error callback, `$.getJSON` does not. So next time you might consider using the more verbose `$.ajax` method so the error callback can help you track down problems.